# RoR: Manage Strings in Rails centrally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string

in a rails project i have to deal with lots of strings, that are used several times in different views. What is the best way to store them centrally so that reusing/maintaing/changing them will be easy in the future? Maybe there are already some conventions i don't know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [I18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) facilities provided by rails. The same principles apply, even if your app has only one language.

Comment: Thank you. I had that already in mind but wasn't sure if thats the "right" way :)